# (TF/Keras Multiple Instance Learning) error during training: Incompatible shapes

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, image-processing, keras

I am trying to reproduce the network similar to what is described in this paper **p64** with Keras: https://ars.els-cdn.com/content/image/1-s2.0-S0140673619329988-mmc1.pdf
However I run into troubles during the training and got the following error:

```
  File "training.py", line 106, in <module>
    model.fit_generator(generator = TrainGenerator(data, train_folder, 64, 1),
  File "/users/name/.conda/envs/tfenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 324, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/users/name/.conda/envs/tfenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1465, in fit_generator
    return self.fit(
  File "/users/name/.conda/envs/tfenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 66, in _method_wrapper
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/users/name/.conda/envs/tfenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 848, in fit
    tmp_logs = train_function(iterator)
  File "/users/name/.conda/envs/tfenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 580, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
  File "/users/name/.conda/envs/tfenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 644, in _call
    return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)
  File "/users/name/.conda/envs/tfenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 2420, in __call__
    return graph_function._filtered_call(args, kwargs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "/users/name/.conda/envs/tfenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 1661, in _filtered_call
    return self._call_flat(
  File "/users/name/.conda/envs/tfenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 1745, in _call_flat
    return self._build_call_outputs(self._inference_function.call(
  File "/users/name/.conda/envs/tfenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 593, in call
    outputs = execute.execute(
  File "/users/name/.conda/envs/tfenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py", line 59, in quick_execute
    tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Invalid argument:  Incompatible shapes: [1,2] vs. [1,20466576]
     [[node LogicalAnd_4 (defined at training.py:106) ]]
     [[assert_less_equal_6/Assert/AssertGuard/pivot_f/_181/_231]]
  (1) Invalid argument:  Incompatible shapes: [1,2] vs. [1,20466576]
     [[node LogicalAnd_4 (defined at training.py:106) ]]
```

I have tried to fix the issue for few days but i couldn't find what is wrong, I would appreciate some help :)

Here is my implementation of the network:

```
mobilenet = MobileNetV2(include_top=True, weights=None, pooling='avg',classes=2)
input_shape = Input(shape=(64, im_size, im_size, 3))
features = TimeDistributed(mobilenet)(input_shape)

x1 = NoisyAnd(2, name = 'pooling')(features)
x2 = Dense(2, activation='softmax', name = 'classification')(x1)

model = Model(inputs=input_shape, outputs=[x1,x2])
model.summary()


model.compile(loss={'classification': 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy', 'pooling':'sparse_categorical_crossentropy'},optimizer=adam, metrics=metrics)
```

with the NoisyAND custom layer (described in this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.05286.pdf) as:

```
class NoisyAnd(Layer):

    def __init__(self, output_dim, **kwargs):
        self.output_dim = output_dim
        super(NoisyAnd, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.a = 10  # fixed, controls the slope of the activation
        self.b = self.add_weight(name='pooling',
                                 shape=(1,2),
                                 initializer='uniform',
                                 trainable=True)
        super(NoisyAnd, self).build(input_shape)  

    def call(self, x):
        mean = tf.reduce_mean(x, axis=[1, 2])
        res = (tf.nn.sigmoid(self.a * (mean - self.b)) - tf.nn.sigmoid(-self.a * self.b)) / (
                tf.nn.sigmoid(self.a * (1 - self.b)) - tf.nn.sigmoid(-self.a * self.b))
        return res

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):

        return 1,2
```

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_21 (InputLayer)        (None, 64, 224, 224, 3)   0         
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_10 (TimeDis (None, 64, 2)             2260546   
_________________________________________________________________
pooling (NoisyAnd)           (2, 1)                    2         
_________________________________________________________________
classification (Activation)  (2, 1)                    0         
=================================================================
Total params: 2,260,548
Trainable params: 2,226,436
Non-trainable params: 34,112
_________________________________________________________________
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

My training inputs are numpy array with shape such as:

```
    X = np.array((batch_size, n_patches, patch_size, patch_size, 3))
    Y = np.array((batch_size))
```

I am using n_patches = 64 and patch_size = 224 (instead of 512 in the paper)

Comment: There quite a few things that do not add up in your question. Your model has 2 outputs... if that is the case the Y parameter to fit needs to be a tuple... the "classification" Dense layer has 2 outputs... but the shape shows up as (2, 1) in the model summary... You don't need to define compute_output_shape on NoisyAdd. Recommendation: Get one batch out of the generator and manually inspect that it has the shape that you and the model expect and fit that 1 batch.

Comment: If i don't define compute_output_shape the problem is that it outputs (None, 64, 2) as shape which should rather be something like (None, 2,1) or (None,2) the number of classes (2 in my case) according to this paper (page4):  https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.05286.pdf

Comment: If Layer.call outputs (None, 64, 2) the situation won't be improved by telling the model graph building that it is actually (1, 2)... at runtime it will still do what the call method defines.

Comment: true, but then shouldn't the layer output shape be the shape of res? what i don't understand then is that res should have the shape of the weight b no?

Comment: When I do something like ```x = tf.constant([[1., 1.],[2., 2.],[2., 3.],[2., 8.],[1., 1.]])
mean = tf.reduce_mean(x, 0)
a = 10
b = tf.constant([ [3.0, 4.0]])
res = (tf.nn.sigmoid(10 * (mean - b)) - tf.nn.sigmoid(-10 * b)) / (tf.nn.sigmoid(10 * (1 - b)) - tf.nn.sigmoid(10 * b))
``` i get a tensor like this <tf.Tensor 'truediv_5:0' shape=(1, 2) dtype=float32> with the correct output shape but when i summarize the model i still get and output shape of (None, 64, 2)

Comment: The input into NoisyAnd has shape (batch, n_patches, 2). where n_patches is 64. So you should try to use an input of such as shape... your x above has shape [5, 2]. it is missing the n_patches dimension.

Comment: This was just a dummy example, but in the end it should work for any n_patches. The aim of this Layer is to "aggregate" the 64 patches and output a probability for each class (in my case i have two classes) but what ever i try it seems that the custom layer wants to have an output shape equal to the input shape which is not what i want